# Need to Concatenate " " inside the string of plsql code oracle apex

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the below XML string inside my PL/SQL block. In the string I need to pass the parameter values, for example: `p_username` is **"admin"** (including the double quotes). Right now I am directly passing the value as **"admin"** but it's not correct. I need to pass only **admin** (without the double quotes). The double quotes needs to be concatenated inside the string.

Relevant block inside my PL/SQL code:

```
<urn:Login>
    <!--TrustedId>$tr.ByRb08A8</TrustedId-->
    <urn:UserName>' || p_username ||
                   '</urn:UserName>
    <urn:Password>' || p_password ||
                   '</urn:Password>
</urn:Login>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<urn:Login>
    <!--TrustedId>$tr.ByRb08A8</TrustedId-->
    <urn:UserName>"' || p_username ||
                  '"</urn:UserName>
    <urn:Password>"' || p_password ||
                  '"</urn:Password>
</urn:Login>
```

Comment: can you pls check one of my another question also "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59136796/how-can-i-extract-only-the-error-message-from-xml-result?noredirect=1#comment104503794_59136796"