# How can I extract only the error message from xml result

Tags: api, oracle11g, oracle-apex, apex-code, oracle-apex-5.1

How can I extract the value from the label `VertexApplicationException` and `User login failed.` from below xml result?

Inside my package, i am using 'make request api' call to get tax value calculated from vertex, sometimes i am getting error as response for my api call, now i need to store the response in table but only i need the error message ex: VertexApplicationException and User login failed. from the belowgiven xml response tag

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <nsf:Fault xmlns:nsf="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <faultcode>nsf:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>User login failed.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns:VertexException xmlns:ns="urn:vertexinc:oseries:exception:1:0">
               <ns:exceptionType>VertexApplicationException</ns:exceptionType>
               <ns:rootCause>User login failed.</ns:rootCause>
            </ns:VertexException>
         </detail>`enter code here`
      </nsf:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an Oracle APEX question? What's the context here?

Comment: yes, inside my package i am using make request api call  to get tax value calculated from vertex, sometimes i am getting error as response for my api call, now i need to store the response in table but only the error message ex: VertexApplicationException and User login failed. from the above given xml response tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query:

```
select a.*  from XMLTABLE (  

  xmlnamespaces( 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'   as "S",   
                 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "nsf",
                 'urn:vertexinc:oseries:exception:1:0' as "ns"),  
  '  
  /S:Envelope/S:Body/nsf:Fault/detail/ns:VertexException
  '  

  PASSING  

  XMLTYPE(  
  '  
  <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <nsf:Fault xmlns:nsf="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <faultcode>nsf:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>User login failed.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns:VertexException xmlns:ns="urn:vertexinc:oseries:exception:1:0">
               <ns:exceptionType>VertexApplicationException</ns:exceptionType>
               <ns:rootCause>User login failed.</ns:rootCause>
            </ns:VertexException>
         </detail>`enter code here`
      </nsf:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>  
  ')  

  columns  
    ExceptionType varchar2(40) path 'ns:exceptionType'  
  , RootCause varchar2(40) path 'ns:rootCause'  
) AS A  
;
```

[**Check DEMO Here**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=272f55192b4ea16e73591c8f4b905f81)

**Output**

```
+----------------------------+--------------------+
| EXCEPTIONTYPE              | ROOTCAUSE          |
+----------------------------+--------------------+
| VertexApplicationException | User login failed. |
+----------------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Thhis would get you darn close, but an XML specific query might also do the job

```
regexp_substr(your_string, '<ns:rootCause>([A-Z]*)(.*)')
```